# Header errors in CLion

Tags: c++, header-files, clion

I met an annoying problem in Clion which is that there are always header errors in my project.
Here is my `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(geometry)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR geo)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR geo)
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/geo/)

set(SOURCE_FILES

    geo/Circle.cpp
    geo/Circle.h
    geo/geo.h
    geo/ICircle.cpp
    geo/ICircle.h
    geo/IPoint.cpp
    geo/IPoint.h
    geo/IRectangle.cpp
    geo/IRectangle.h
    geo/IShape.cpp
    geo/IShape.h
    geo/IText.cpp
    geo/IText.h
    geo/Point.cpp
    geo/Point.h
    geo/Rectangle.cpp
    geo/Rectangle.h
    geo/Shape.cpp
    geo/Shape.h
    geo/Text.cpp
    geo/Text.h
    owl/IThing.cpp
    owl/IThing.h
    owl/owl.h
    owl/Thing.cpp
    owl/Thing.h
    rdfs/IResource.cpp
    rdfs/IResource.h
    rdfs/rdfs.h
    rdfs/Resource.cpp
    rdfs/Resource.h
    AllInOne.cpp
    example.cpp
    geometry.owl)

add_executable(geometry ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Here is the `example.cpp` which is also the main cpp:

```
#include <autordf/Factory.h>

#include <geo/geo.h>

using namespace geo;


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    autordf::Factory f;
    f.addNamespacePrefix("geo", "http://example.org/geometry#");
    autordf::Object::setFactory(&f);

    geo::Rectangle r("http://example.org/myfancyrectangle");

    // Set one of my rectangle coordinates - the long way
    geo::Point tl;
    tl.setX(1.0);
    tl.setY(2.0);
    r.setTopLeft(tl);

    // Set one of my rectangle coordinates - the short way
    r.setBottomRight(geo::Point().setX(11).setY(12));

    // Set result of my work
    f.saveToFile(stdout, "turtle");
}
```

It works perfectly in the terminal but in Clion the result is:

```
Scanning dependencies of target geometry
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/Circle.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/ICircle.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/IPoint.cpp.o
/home/burning/projects/autordf_projects/geometry/geo/Circle.cpp:2:24: fatal error: geo/Circle.h: No such file or directory
 #include <geo/Circle.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
/home/burning/projects/autordf_projects/geometry/geo/ICircle.cpp:2:25: fatal error: geo/ICircle.h: No such file or directory
 #include <geo/ICircle.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
/home/burning/projects/autordf_projects/geometry/geo/IPoint.cpp:2:24: fatal error: geo/IPoint.h: No such file or directory
 #include <geo/IPoint.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/IRectangle.cpp.o
/home/burning/projects/autordf_projects/geometry/geo/IRectangle.cpp:2:28: fatal error: geo/IRectangle.h: No such file or directory
 #include <geo/IRectangle.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/ICircle.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/Circle.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/IPoint.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/geo/IRectangle.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [geometry] Error 2
```

One of the header files in `geo/` (e.g. `Circle.cpp`) looks like:

```
/** @cond internal */
#include <geo/Circle.h>

// This is auto generated code by AutoRDF, do not edit !

namespace geo {

Circle::Circle(const std::string& iri) : autordf::Object(iri, ICircle::TYPEIRI) {
}

Circle::Circle(const Object& other) : autordf::Object(other) {
}

std::vector<Circle> Circle::find() {
    return findHelper<Circle>(ICircle::TYPEIRI);
}

}

/** @endcond internal */
```

So, the problem is that I cannot include the other headers in the header file. As you can see above the error would be:

```
/home/burning/projects/autordf_projects/geometry/geo/Circle.cpp:2:24: fatal error: geo/Circle.h: No such file or directory
 #include <geo/Circle.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

Could someone help me with that?

Comment: I don't think you read the documentation for `CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR`, `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR`, and `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use:

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

Instead of:

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

From the documentation of [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html), we have that:

> Top level source directory for the current project.

From the documentation of [`PROJECT_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.html), we have that:

> Full path to build directory for project.

Thus, unless you allow in-source builds for your projects, it's likely that you want to use the source directory as an include directory, **not** the build directory.